# Direct and Indirect object pronoun placement?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

For my French studies, I must translate this sentence into French, but I am struggling with understanding pronoun placement.

*Context:
'He sent the book to David at high school.' = 'Il a envoyé le livre à David au lycée.'*

**Sentence:
'He already sent it to him there.' = ???**

*What I've come up with:
'Il déjà le lui y a envoyé.'*

Is that anywhere near correct? Can you give me an example of how you would form this sentence, and how you would form it if it were a negative? E.g. 'He hasn't already sent it to him there.'

Answer (score 2):

You are close. In that kind of sentences, the adverb *déjà* is normally located between the verb and the past participle so the correct form (if any) is:

> *Il le lui y a déjà envoyé.*

That's a lot of pronouns though, so you would hear instead:

> Il le lui a déjà envoyé.

or simply:

> Il lui a déjà envoyé.

If *there* need to be specified, *là-bas* might be used instead of *y*:

> Il le lui a déjà envoyé là-bas.

or

> Il lui a déjà envoyé là-bas.

Negative is built using *ne pas* with *ne* immediately following the subject and *pas* after the verb, e.g.:

> Il ne lui a pas déjà envoyé.

Comment: I think it's : "Il l'a déjà envoyé".

Comment: @Chris That would remove some pieces of information.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It's definitely more of a hypothetical statement for study purposes rather than a practical one!

Comment: Yes right. Then the good one is « Il le lui a déjà envoyé ». « Il le lui y a déjà envoyé » sounds wrong when I read it.

Answer (score 1):

> Il le lui y a déjà envoyé.

And for the negative form, *déjà* become *encore*.

> Il ne le lui y a pas encore envoyé.

Good [reference](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/315.html) for pronoun order.

But i think both sentence are just for academic purpose. It's not really easy to understand sentence like that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! And thank you for the reference, I'll definitely use it. Yeah, this is definitely more of a hypothetical statement for study purposes rather than a practical one. It was tricky for me to wrap my head around so many pronoms!